Tradingview Widget Set Different colors to differnt moving average
This is my code
function LoadCharts() {
    let symbol = document.getElementById('pairs').value;

    // List of symbols for each chart
    const symbols = ['BTCUSDT.P', 'ETHUSDT.P', 'BCHUSDT.P', 'XRPUSDT.P', 'LTCUSDT.P', 'TRXUSDT.P', 'ETCUSDT.P', 'LINKUSDT.P', 'XLMUSDT.P',
              'ADAUSDT.P', 'XMRUSDT.P', 'DASHUSDT.P', 'ZECUSDT.P', 'BNBUSDT.P', 'ATOMUSDT.P', 'VETUSDT.P', 'NEOUSDT.P', 'QTUMUSDT.P',
              'IOSTUSDT.P', 'THETAUSDT.P', 'KNCUSDT.P', 'ZRXUSDT.P', 'COMPUSDT.P', 'OMGUSDT.P', 'DOGEUSDT.P', 'SXPUSDT.P', 'KAVAUSDT.P',
              'BANDUSDT.P', 'RLCUSDT.P', 'MKRUSDT.P', 'DOTUSDT.P', 'DEFIUSDT.P', 'YFIUSDT.P', 'BALUSDT.P', 'TRBUSDT.P',
              'RUNEUSDT.P', 'SUSHIUSDT.P', 'EGLDUSDT.P', 'SOLUSDT.P', 'STORJUSDT.P', 'BLZUSDT.P', 'UNIUSDT.P', 'AVAXUSDT.P', 'FTMUSDT.P',
              'ENJUSDT.P', 'KSMUSDT.P', 'NEARUSDT.P', 'AAVEUSDT.P', 'FILUSDT.P', 'RSRUSDT.P'];

    // Add delay between each chart load with a different symbol
    for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var widget = window.tvWidget = new TradingView.widget({
                "width": chartWidth, // Chart width
                "height": chartHeight, // Chart height
                "symbol": "BINANCE:" + symbols[i % symbols.length], // Use a different symbol for each chart
                "interval": "5", // You can vary intervals if needed
                "timezone": "Asia/Kolkata",
                "hide_side_toolbar": false,
                "hide_volume": false,
                "theme": "Dark",
                "style": "1",
                "locale": "out",
                "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
                "enable_publishing": false,
                "allow_symbol_change": true,
                "details": true,
                "container_id": 'tvchart' + i,
                "studies": [
                    {id: "MAExp@tv-basicstudies",inputs: {length: 7}},
                    {id: "MAExp@tv-basicstudies",inputs: {length: 25}},
                    {id: "MAExp@tv-basicstudies",inputs: {length: 99}}],
            });
        }, i * 2000); // Delay of 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds) between each chart
    }
}

I tried this....
{id: "MAExp@tv-basicstudies",inputs: {length: 7},style:{color:"#FFFF00"}}

I have searched a lot to solve this problem but I am unable to do it. How can I plot multiple emas with different colours?

Most likely in the .js file there's a class TradingView or function TradingView  or var TradingView that actually accepts the parameters. It's easier to just load it like normal then use the devtools to find the element and use CSS to change the style. There are too many possibilities. If you were to post the code as a [mcve] (hint: click the brackets button <>), it would be easier to assist you.
